# Fetching all objects of one class with self-referencing ManyToMany

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Think of this class:

```
class Person {

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Person", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     */
    public $friends;
   /**
     *
     * @var Person
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person")
     */
    public $bestFriend;
}
```

I have to iterate a lot over all Persons, so I'd like to fetch join them all at once.
To save memory, I have to do this partially.

So what I can do is:

```
$this->em->createQuery('SELECT partial p.{id, name, bestFriend} FROM Person p')->getResult();
```

This is cool, after this query, all persons are in the UoW, and I can traverse the graph via `$aPersion->bestFriend->bestFriend` without creating an additional query to the DB, since all Persons are in memory.

However, this does not  work with the ToMany association. Adding `friends` to the partial select gives an error. If I want to iterate over all friends, this will first create a query to the join table...

How can I realise the full hydration of the `friends`-ToMany-assotiation with one query? Maybe a second query could help? Or a clever join clause?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a query in `PersonRepository.php` with a `leftJoin` and a `addSelect` like so:

```
$qb = $this->em->getRepository('App:Person')
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.friends', 'friends')
    ->select('partial p.{id, name, bestFriend}'}
    ->addSelect('partial friends.{id, name}') // Retrieve what you want here
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
return $qb;
```

I have not tested this, but believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

@DirkJFaber your answer was right,

in terms of DQL here is my solution:

```
$this->em->createQuery('
    SELECT partial p.{id, name, bestFriend}, f FROM Person p JOIN f.friends f')->getResult();
```